# Binding Source not being updated when controls are updated by user (VB.NET Winforms)

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, winforms, dataset

This should be simple but is not working.  I am a simple form with controls that are being populated by a database via a table adapter and bindingsource.  The code for the Form_Load event is here:

```
Me.DS_Phantom_Location_taLocation1.Fill(Me.DS_Phantom_Location1.dtLocation, CType(resultnum, Integer))
    bsLocation.DataSource = Me.DS_Phantom_Location1.dtLocation
```

This part works fine and the controls are updated with the data in the database.

When the user clicks the OK button the database is supposed to be updated, but it's not happening.

The code is here:

```
Me.bsLocation.EndEdit()
Me.DS_Phantom_Location_taLocation1.Update(DS_Phantom_Location1.dtLocation)
```

I know from looking at the underlying datarow that the bindingsource is not being update - this is also within the btnok_click event:

```
    Dim drv As DataRowView = TryCast(Me.bsLocation.Current, DataRowView)
    Dim dr As DataRow = drv.Row
    s = dr("INSTITUTION_DOSE").ToString
```

s is still the old value from the database.

It looks like the bsLocation never gets updated.  I ensured the control has the causesvalidation = true and the control is databound (remember it gets populated just fine).

At this point I'm not sure what to do beyond just scrap the bindingsource idea and use the table adapter to directly update.  I know this works, but it's not ideal, especially for large forms with 50 or so controls. (which my project has).  Any help/ideas would be awesome.  Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after way too long on this, i troubleshot it back to the dataset, the SQL I used to generate the data had many TRIM() functions which causes the column aliasing to be messed up, and most of the columns were set to read only, and the UPDATE comment from the table adapter actually only had a few database columns in it.  So removing the TRIM() functions and rebuilding the commands worked, and now it updates as proper.